# Direct access to S3 Glacier Deep Archive

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, aws-sdk-net

Using latest .NET SDK, I cannot find any way to upload/download direct to Glacier Deep Archive (avoiding S3 bucket and transitioning).

**Is it possible? if not, are there plans to do enable that in future?**

*I mean - it is possible (and is a good idea) to have direct access to regular Glacier.. Deep Archive is even more suitable for it yet its not available..*

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

It appears that Glacier Deep Archive is provided an as Amazon S3 storage class, but is not available as a 'direct-to-Glacier' storage option.

Amazon Glacier is now called **Amazon S3 Glacier**, which that suggests a focus on tighter integration with Amazon S3. This is probably good, because directly interacting with Glacier has always been quite laborious, involving jobs and inventories.

Comment: its not abt devs convenience. its for customers. deep archive means "proper" archive - upload and forget. managing S3 buckets for something you need once a decade seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have been trying to find an answer to this question myself.

The workaround that I've found right now is to have all objects in the bucket of interest migrate to S3 Glacier Deep Archive after 0 days. (need to set a policy or w/e)

Comment: is there an additional cost to upload data to the S3 bucket and then transfer it to Glacier deep archive?